# Typescript reconstruct original type from Omit type

Tags: typescript

In typescript 3.5, [`Omit` helper is added](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html).
Let's say a 3rd party API provides the following interface and function:

```
interface Params {
    n: number;
    s: string;
    b: boolean;
    on: number;
    os: string;
    ob: boolean;
}

function api(params: Params) {...}
```

I want to write a wrapper to `api` so that I only need to expose interesting properties to the rest of my codebase.

```
function wrapper(params: Omit<Params, 'on' | 'os' | 'ob'>) {
    (params as Params).on = 1;
    (params as Params).os = 'foo';
    (params as Params).ob = false;
    api(params as Params);
}
```

This looks like a hack to me due to the usage of `as`. What is the most elegant way to achieve this so that

1. Type check passes
2. Type check can catch if I assign a wrong type to omitted properties (e.g. `params.on = 'bar';`) This can be caught in the current implementation.
3. Type check can catch if I miss any omitted property (e.g. `on` is not assigned in the wrapper) This won't be caught in the current implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options that I can think of:

```
// Option 1: Object spread
type WrapperParms = Omit<Params, 'on' | 'os' | 'ob'>;
function wrapper(params: WrapperParms) {
    return api({
      on: 1,
      os: 'foo',
      ob: false,
      ...params
    });
}

// Option 2: Optionals + default values + Object spread
type FilteredParams = 'on' | 'os' | 'ob';
type OptionalParams = Partial<Pick<Params, FilteredParams>>;
type WrapperParams2 = Omit<Params, FilteredParams> & OptionalParams;
function wrapper2(params: WrapperParams2) {
    // assign default values to optional parameters
    const {on = 1, os = 'foo', ob = false, ...rest} = params;
    return api({
      on,
      os,
      ob,
      ...rest
    });
}
```

With the second option, type definitions may seem more complex but they provide more flexibility to users of the wrapper function. This effectively convert omitted properties to optional properties, so they may provide alternative values of the wrapped parameters.

Comment: Wow, nice solution with extras (option 2). Just want to point out that if wrapper should force the omitted properties to be specific values, in option 1, `...params` should be placed at the beginning (before `on`). Thanks a lot!